# Javascript Replace - Dynamic Value of Replacement

Tags: javascript

I have a template in a String and I want to replace a few of the placeholders with the values that I have in another string. For every placeholder that I replace, I also want to insert a break tag.

For eg if `#ADDRESS2#` is found in the template, I am using the following code to replace all its occurrences with value in string `val.address2`.

```
    template_html = template_html.replace(/#ADDRESS2#/g, '<br />'+ val.address_2);
```

However there are scenarios when the string `val.address2` is empty. In that case, I do not want to insert the break tag.

So I changed my code as follows

```
    if( val.address_2.length > 0 ) {
        template_html = template_html.replace(/#ADDRESS2#/g, '<br />'+ val.address_2);
    } else {
        template_html = template_html.replace(/#ADDRESS2#/g, '');
    }
```

Is there a better way to write the above code as I have multiple Placeholders and for each Placeholder I have to write the code 2 times.

Comment: Since jQuery is (primarily) a DOM manipulation library, it's not really relevant here. I've removed that tag.

Comment: why not use same template strings in the text and in the objects. it makes it easier to just replace with the same string.

Comment: Can you show more of those "multiple Placeholders" that you have? E.g. are they all quite regular or not, and how do they relate to the property names used for the replacement?

Comment: @nina yes, I can change the template to have same name as string.

Comment: @peter other vplaceholders are like City, State, zip. I can make the placeholder name same as object if that helps

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a regex replacement, to which you pass a function.

That function will get the replacement keys as input, and depending on if there's a replacement available, it will insert a empty string, or the replacement with a linebreak:

```js
const template = "#foo# this bla bla #bar# but #baz# and stuff";

const replacements = {
  foo: "test",
  bar: "",
  baz: "not empty"
};

const result = template.replace(/#([^#]+)#/g, (match, key) => {
  // If there's a replacement for the key, return that replacement with a `<br />`. Otherwise, return a empty string.
  return replacements[key] !== undefined
    ? "<br />" + replacements[key]
    : "";
});

console.log("template:", template);
console.log("result:", result);
```

The only "gotcha" here is that the keys in the template string have to match the keys in your replacements object. That's not necessarily a bad thing, though, as it would make it slightly more intuitive if you'd look back at your code later on.

The regex may look intimidating, but it's really quite simple:

`/#([^#]+)#/g`

- `/`: The start of the regex,
- `#`: Literally the `#` character,
- `(`: The start of a capturing group,
- `[^#]+` Any character that isn't a `#`. The `+` makes sure it matches as many as possible,
- `)`: The end of a capturing group,
- `#`: Literally the `#` character,
- `/g`: The end of the regex. `g` is the global flag, so it doesn't stop at the first result.

The capturing group basically tells the regex to group everything that's between the brackets. The groups are then returned individually.

Comment: Thanks this worked. Also thanks for explaining the regex used

Comment: I'm glad to be of help. The "accept" vote is appreciated :-)

Comment: @Cerbrus you could capture a group `.replace(/#([^#]+)#/g, (match, key) => {` to avoid removing `#` with second regex

Comment: @barbsan: That's much better! Thanks for the tip :D

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you meant this?

```js
var val = {
  "address_1": "Address 1",
  "address_2": "",
  "address_10": "Address 10",
}  
var template_html = `My address is #ADDRESS1# delivery address is #ADDRESS2# and billing is #ADDRESS10#`
template_html = template_html.replace(/#ADDRESS(\d+)#/g, function(addr, num) { 
  var str = val["address_"+num]; return str?str+"<br/>":""
})
console.log(template_html)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the same logic should be applied for multiple address fields, then you might benefit from a helper function:

```
template_html = template_html
    .replace(/#CITY1#/g, PrefixBrIfNotEmpty(val.city_1))
    .replace(/#CITY2#/g, PrefixBrIfNotEmpty(val.city_2))
    .replace(/#CITY3#/g, PrefixBrIfNotEmpty(val.city_3))
    .replace(/#ADDRESS1#/g, PrefixBrIfNotEmpty(val.address_1))
    .replace(/#ADDRESS2#/g, PrefixBrIfNotEmpty(val.address_2))
    .replace(/#ADDRESS3#/g, PrefixBrIfNotEmpty(val.address_3));

function PrefixBrIfNotEmpty(str) {
    return str ? '<br />' + str : '';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could take the value with a check.

```
template_html = template_html.replace(
    /#ADDRESS2#/g,
    val.address_2 && '<br />' + val.address_2
);
```

For more than one placeholder, you could take a dynamic approach and use same pattern for the search and replacements.

```js
var val = { address_2: 'foo', country_1: 'bar' }
    template_html = 'Address: #ADDRESS2#\nCountry: #COUNTRY1#\nnothing: #NOTHING#'

template_html = template_html.replace(
    /#([^#]+)#/g,
    (_, group) => {
        var key = group.match(/^(\D+)(\d*)$/).slice(1).map(s => s.toLowerCase()).join('_');

        return (val[key] || '') && '<br />' + val[key];
     }
);
console.log(template_html);
```

For getting a smarter replacement, yoou could take the idea of same strings as tempate and for getting the data from an object. In this case, take the replacement value and take this as key for the object or take an empty string for unknown values.

```js
var val = { ADDRESS2: 'foo', COUNTRY1: 'bar' }
    template_html = 'Address: #ADDRESS2#\nCountry: #COUNTRY1#\nnothing: #NOTHING#'

template_html = template_html.replace(
    /#([^#]+)#/g,
    (_, key) => (val[key] || '') && '<br />' + val[key]
);
console.log(template_html);
```

Comment: Well, I've said this before, but you have a way of making code _work_, but hard to understand. Maybe that's why some people downvoted the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ternary operator (empty string evaluates to false)

```
template_html = template_html.replace(/#ADDRESS2#/g, val.address_2 ? '<br />'+ val.address_2 : '');
```

Comment: This replacement would still have to be programmed for every replacement key the OP wants to replace.

Comment: Yes, but it's still shorter than `if else` block

Comment: Still, multiple placeholders is part of the OP's problem.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest change is to use the ternary operator like this:

```
template_html = template_html.replace(/#ADDRESS2#/g, ( val.address_2.length > 0 ) ? '<br />'+ val.address_2 : '');
```

Still not particularly elegant but a bit shorter than the original.

Comment: This replacement would still have to be programmed for every replacement key the OP wants to replace.

Answer (score -1):

You mean, something like this:

```
template_html = template_html.replace(/#ADDRESS(\d+)#/g, function(address, number) {
    return val.hasOwnProperty('address_' + number)
        ? '<br />' + val['address_' + number]
        : '';
};
```

You should use the `val.hasOwnProperty` just in case that `val.['address_' + number]` contains a value like `0`, `false`, `''`, `undefined`, `NaN` or other falsy values.
It makes sure the value is displayed anyway, because an `undefined` isn't the same as not having the property at all.

It also avoids to get a value from the prototype, just in case.

This is based on [mplungjan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) answer.

---

If this is undesirable, and you only want to show strings, try this:

```
template_html = template_html.replace(/#ADDRESS(\d+)#/g, function(address, number) {
    return val.hasOwnProperty('address_' + number)
    && val['address_' + number].length
    && (
        (typeof val['address_' + number]) === 'string'
        || val['address_' + number] instanceof String
    )
        ? '<br />' + val['address_' + number]
        : '';
};
```

All of this checking ensures that it is a non-empty string (or `String` instance, because `new String()` returns a string object).
Checking if it is an instance of `String` prevents issues due to `typeof new String()` returning `object`.

Arrays and array-like objects have a `length` attributes (e.g.: jQuery instance, NodeList, `{length: 1}`, `[0]` and similars), but you dont want to show them as strings.

Comment: Why would the `val` object contain arrays though?

Comment: @Cerbrus Why wouldn't it? It is just an object. The O.P. didn't specify that it wouldn't have an array, or that it would be guaranteed to only have strings or no value at all. As far as I know, you can do `var val = {address2: [] }`, as it is part of the basics of JavaScript. Since nothins much was specified about `val`, there's nothing wrong about taking some extra care.

Comment: It seems excessive, just as the combination of a `typeof` _and_ a `instanceOf` check. One makes the other redundant.

Comment: Not really. As I've explained, `new String()` returns a string object, which acts like a string literal in every single aspect, except when checking the type with `typeof`, which returns `object` instead of the expected `string`. Also, doing `'' instanceof String` returns false. But yes, it is a bit excessive.